# Software for Hilbert series of quotients of exterior algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, mathematical-software

Is there some software which computes Hilbert series of quotients of exterior algebras? In commutative case, Maple can compute Hilbert series. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macaulay2 (M2) is good for Hilbert series computations and can do exterior algebras. You can see the [documentation](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_exterior_spalgebras.html) for exterior algebras in M2 for more info. Below is a quick example of a Hilbert series computation.

```
i1 : R = QQ[a..d,SkewCommutative=>true];

i2 : I = ideal(a+b+c+d);

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : M = R/I;

i4 : reduceHilbert hilbertSeries M

                2    3
     1 + 3T + 3T  + T
o4 = -----------------
             1

o4 : Expression of class Divide
```